# How many people in the world have bad eyesight?

Tags: genetics, eyes

I was watching this [ted.ed](http://ed.ted.com/lessons/how-do-glasses-help-us-see-andrew-bastawrous-and-clare-gilbert) episode and heard it was around 500,000 but that didn't sound right-- does anyone know?

Comment: Depends on how you define bad eye sight? Visual function is not either good or bad; it's a range.

Answer (score 3):

I do know that [the TED Ed episode linked](http://ed.ted.com/lessons/how-do-glasses-help-us-see-andrew-bastawrous-and-clare-gilbert) (at 3:50) actually says that 500 million people have myopia or hyperopia, which is 1000 times what the question says, and which seems more reasonable for a world of 7.4 billion people (skewed towards the young).